# Which page hit the wordpress default blog navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I am novice in wordpress. Recently i create a blog which home page shows the recent 10 post. When it increase more than 10 post then it show next page link. This link is generated by below code :

```
<div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
```

When i click this link it goes *http://example.com/page/2/* and show **Error 404 - Page Not Found**

I put **page.php, blog.php** in my theme but it still shows same error. So now i wanted to know which page hit the wordpress default blog navigation ?

Thanks.

Comment: In worpress the default blog page is index.php. All post are showing on that page.

Comment: Flush your permalinks.

Comment: If you don't know how to do that, here is a helpful link: http://wp-bytes.com/function/2013/02/flushing-permalinks/
Sometimes you should click the Save button twice, just to be extra sure.

Comment: Thanks everyone i found my solution. My problem was in the home page(home.php), i was putting this code `<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=10');?>`. After removing this code, now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue Goto permalinks in wordpress, from there choose the link structure. And it will give you the lines of code.

Open FTP to access .htaccess file in website and just paste the code. It will simply work.

Happy Coding!

Atul